# How do domestic stimulus packages affect other nations?

Tags: macroeconomics

Suppose a country decided to implement a new stimulus package as a way to energize the economy. Wikipedia defines two types of stimulus:

> **Fiscal stimulus** refers to increasing government consumption or
>   transfers or lowering taxes. Effectively this means increasing the
>   rate of growth of public debt, except that particularly Keynesians
>   often assume that the stimulus will cause sufficient economic growth
>   to fill that gap partially or completely. See multiplier (economics).
>   **Monetary stimulus** refers to lowering interest rates, quantitative
>   easing, or other ways of increasing the amount of money or credit.

What effect would each of these stimulus types generally have on nations other than the country that tries the stimulus? Will the main trading partners be affected the most? Who benefits more, exporters or importers? Does it depend on the particular details of the stimulus package? Does it cause the other nations to start their own stimulus program?

I am looking for theoretical (analytical) responses, not necessarily something that is backed by empirical evidence.

Comment: I have a feeling that your question may be too broad. It'll probably take a couple chapters in an international finance/trade textbook to provide a proper answer. Can you narrow down your question a bit? Maybe one stimulus at a time? And reduce the number of questions listed in the second last paragraph would help.